# How to check if a string is contained in another substring using "indexOf" and "for" iterator in Java Language?

Tags: java, for-loop, substring, indexof

I'm new to programming in Java so I'd like some help on this matter, thank you very much for your time :)

I want to check if "**CheckAutonomy**" is contained in a substring using indexOf and a for iterator to iterate trough my objects,(ambient contains 4 objects everytime, this is the "wouldbe" code :

ReEdit: I added more details, i hope this will be enough , i really don't know how to grasp it :|

```
    public static void scrivi(JSONArray jsa, String nome, String versione ) throws IOException{

    for(int j = 0; j < jsa.length(); j++){
        JSONArray endpoint = jsa.getJSONArray(j);

        bsrURI = getObjectValueFromJSONArrayEndpointData(endpoint, "bsrURI");

        String query = normalizeQuery(QUERY_GET_BSRURI, null, null, null,  bsrURI);
        JSONArray jsaUriBSR = queryExecutor(query);

        /*???
        for(i = o; i < 3; i++){
        if (ambient.contains("CheckAutonomy")){
        }
        }
        ???*/

        String ambient = jsaUriBSR.get(0).toString()
                                .substring(  jsaUriBSR.get(0).toString().indexOf('#') + 1, jsaUriBSR.get(0).toString().length() - 2 );



        System.out.println(ambient);
        }*/

        String line = ambient + ";\n";

        bw.write(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no `for` loop in your code

Comment: Where are you checking for "CheckAutonomy"?

Comment: Assuming that the `0` in `get(0)`is the value you want to iterate over, and that `ambient` is the string you want to check, you can use `ambient.contains("CheckAutonomy")` to check if it contains the value as a substring. `contains(…)` is the same as `indexOf(…) >= 0`.

Comment: You need to supply code that makes some sense because your current example doesn't and you also need to state more clearly what your issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with something like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++){
        if (risultato.get(i).toString().contains("CheckAutonomy"))
                 ambient = result.get(i).toString()
                .substring(  result.get(i).toString().indexOf('#') + 1, 
 result.get(i).toString().length() - 2 );

    }
```

Nevertheless, thank you for your time ! :P